# Laravel resource routing: why is the path */create set on GET method instead of POST?

Tags: rest, laravel, routes

As per title, why should the requests toward `*/create` (E.g: `user/create`) use the GET method instead of the POST method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user/create` is the route for the HTML form to create a user.

It should `POST` to `user` (which fires the `store` method).

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking too, but the `php artisan routes` command tells me that this is the URI for `user/create`: `GET|HEAD user/create`

Comment: @siannone And? I don't see why that's a "but". http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-artisan-route-gethead

Comment: Sorry, I replied before reading the updated answer. Now it makes sense. Thank you.